# Get posted selected value from radio button in view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a view where I am showing up to 5 radio buttons as follows:

**View**

```
foreach(var item in Model.AvailableOptions)
{
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Option, item.OptionId, new { Id = item.Id});
}
```

**Model**

```
IList<Options> AvailableOptions {get; set;}
```

Then I have a javascript on the same view that handles changing some forms on the page. For example if I have 5 radio buttons when I click upon each of them I hide the form and show the next one etc..

The problem is that if there are 5 radio buttons and I am on the third one and I submit with some invalid entries in the form, when it returns to the page it sets it to the first radio button as selected. I would like to know which one was selected on the Submit so that I can reset it on the javascript.

I would like something like (just not sure how to do this)

```
var selectedValue =  '@(int)Model.SomehowRetrieveTheValuePosted';
```

Then I would be able to do:

```
jQuery(".radioOptions")[selectedValue].show();
```

or something like that.

Comment: You cant bind radio buttons (or any control) to a complex object (typeof `Option`) - you need to bind to a value type property.

Comment: Can you share an example if you may?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model needs a property to bind the selected option, for example

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
  IList<Options> AvailableOptions {get; set;}
}
```

View

```
foreach(var option in Model.AvailableOptions)
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedOption , option.OptionId, new { Id = option.Id});
  // assume Option contains a property Name for display
  <label for="@option.Id">@option.Name</label> 
}
```

If the value of `SelectedOption` matches the `Id` of one of the options, it will be selected when the page is first displayed. If you select another option, that option will be selected if you post and return the view.

Side note: Since your not generating any controls for `Options`, you need to ensure you reassign the value of options if you return the view.

Comment: So would i still need to assign it in jquery? where would i find the selected on the html?. Thanks a lot.. I will add a property like that :).

Comment: No, jquery is not required. The MVC framework takes care of all the binding.